# How to stop long executing threads gracefully?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a threading problem with Delphi. I guess this is common in other languages too. I have a long process which I do in a thread, that fills a list in main window. But if some parameters change in the mean time, then I should stop current executing thread and start from the beginning. Delphi suggests terminating a thread by setting Terminated:=true and checking for this variable's value in the thread. However my problem is this, the long executing part is buried in a library call and in this call I cannot check for the Terminated variable. Therefore I had to wait for this library call to finish, which affects the whole program.

What is the preferred way to do in this case? Can I kill the thread immediately?

Comment: What is the long-running library call?

Answer (score 9):

The preferred way is to modify the code so that it doesn't block without checking for cancellation.

Since you can't modify the code, you can't do that; you either have to live with the background operation (but you can disassociate it from any UI, so that its completion will be ignored); or alternatively, you can try terminating it (TerminateThread API will rudely terminate any thread given its handle). Termination isn't clean, though, like Rob says, any locks held by the thread will be abandoned, and any cross-thread state protected by such locks may be in a corrupted state.

Can you consider calling the function in a separate executable? Perhaps using RPC (pipes, TCP, rather than shared memory owing to same lock problem), so that you can terminate a process rather than terminating a thread? Process isolation will give you a good deal more protection. So long as you aren't relying on cross-process named things like mutexes, it should be far safer than killing a thread.

Comment: This sounds as a good advice. Making this call in another process will leave no trails after forfeiting it.

Answer (score 3):

The threads need to co-operate to achieve a graceful shutdown.  I am not sure if Delphi offers a mechanism to abort another thread, but such mechanisms are available in .NET and Java, but should be considered an option of last resort, and the state of the application is indeterminate after they have been used.

If you can kill a thread at an arbitrary point, then you may kill it while it is holding a lock in the memory allocator (for example).  This will leave your program open to hanging when your main thread next needs to access that lock.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't modify the code to check for termination, then just set its priority really low, and ignore it when it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in reply to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209086/how-do-i-guarantee-fast-shutdown-of-my-win32-app#210385):

> I use an exception-based technique
>   that's worked pretty well for me in a
>   number of Win32 applications.
>
> To terminate a thread, I use
>   QueueUserAPC to queue a call to a
>   function which throws an exception.
>   However, the exception that's thrown
>   isn't derived from the type
>   "Exception", so will only be caught by
>   my thread's wrapper procedure.

I've used this with C++Builder apps very successfully. I'm not aware of all the subtleties of Delphi vs C++ exception handling, but I'd expect it could easily be modified to work.