# Kill the Thread in android

Tags: java, android

I'm using 3rd party library for doing some work in my application. Unfortunately, some bugs were found in it and they cause very sad result: my app is hanging as worker thread probably infinite looping. I've read some questions about killing the thread in android VM but they are didn't help me because of:

1. stop() method is deprecated and not supported bu Andriod VM
2. interrupt() method doesn't do anything, i mean thread is still alive

The worst thing is that from some moment of time this worker thread starts to use a lot of memory causing GC to run too often which also is not good for app.

I've found some conditions when bug in library is occurred but i there are may be other bugs which i also want to avoid in my app.

Here is ode snippet that shows the problem:

```
                final MutableObject<Object> calculationResult = new MutableObject<Object>(null);
            final MutableObject<EvalError> exception = new MutableObject<EvalError>(null);
            final MutableObject<Thread> calculationThread = new MutableObject<Thread>(null);

            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
                    try {
                        Log.d(CalculatorEngine.class.getName(), "Calculation thread started work: " + thread.getName());
                        calculationThread.setObject(thread);
                        calculationResult.setObject(interpreter.eval(jsclExpression));
                    } catch (EvalError evalError) {
                        exception.setObject(evalError);
                    } finally {
                        Log.d(CalculatorEngine.class.getName(), "Calculation thread ended work: " + thread.getName());
                        calculationThread.setObject(null);
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            try {
                Log.d(CalculatorEngine.class.getName(), "Main thread is waiting: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                latch.await(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Log.d(CalculatorEngine.class.getName(), "Main thread got up: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                final EvalError evalErrorLocal = exception.getObject();
                final Object calculationResultLocal = calculationResult.getObject();
                final Thread calculationThreadLocal = calculationThread.getObject();

                if (calculationThreadLocal != null) {
                    // todo serso: interrupt doesn't stop the thread but it MUST be killed
                    calculationThreadLocal.interrupt();
                    resetInterpreter();
                }

                if ( evalErrorLocal != null ) {
                    throw evalErrorLocal;
                }

                if ( calculationResultLocal == null ) {
                    tooLongExecutionCache.add(jsclExpression);
                    throw new ParseException("Too long calculation for: " + jsclExpression);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new ParseException(e);
            }
```

Comment: You need to read these threads - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255276/how-to-stop-long-executing-threads-gracefully

Comment: The links are irrelevant. The third party library is looping because of a bug and se.solovyev is asking for a watchdog killswitch.

Comment: KarlP is right, but thanks to AVD i at least can reduce the effects of the bug (i mean i can set low priority for such threads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread could not be killed in davlik:
I used solution proposed by AVD and just set the priority of thread to lowest possible value and invoke `interrupt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

System.exit() might at least kill your application, if you can detect that the task has stopped responding.

Comment: I think it's completely not user friendly.

Comment: Haha, better than draining the battery, perhaps.