# Efficient exit from multithreaded application (specifics)

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, exit

I've read a few sources on proper methods of bubbling a message out from a thread to all other threads to exit gracefully (every thread performs it's own exit routine). Of these, I liked the idea of a global atomic boolean that can be flagged from any thread, and all other threads check this flag to perform an exit routine - when all threads are joined, the main thread can then exit the application.

Purely computation threads would probably be handled differently, right?

Is this efficient and safe? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, I use QueueUserAPC to call a function which throws an exception, causing threads to exit cleanly.

I wrote more about the details in this answer here:

[How do I guarantee fast shutdown of my win32 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209086/how-do-i-guarantee-fast-shutdown-of-my-win32-app/210385#210385)

In summary, here's what happens:

Say thread A wants to terminate thread B (and then C, D, ...)

- Thread A calls `QueueUserAPC()`, passing the handle to thread B and the address of a function which will throw an Exception of class MyThreadExit.
- Thread B runs normally until it calls something that checks for alertable waits. Maybe `WaitForSingleObjectEx`, maybe `SleepEx`, or something else.
- At this point, thread B runs the APC function passed earlier, causing the exception to be thrown in Thread B.
- All stack-allocated objects get automatically destructed correctly as the exception makes thread B 'unwind' its stack.
- The outermost thread function of thread B will catch the exception.
- Thread B now exits, possibly signalling to Thread A that it's done.

Comment: sounds smart, but I just can't shake the "this is way too hacky" feeling every time I read it...

Comment: I'll admit it's non-portable, but most other solutions really restrict what third-party code you can use in your threads. I use threads heavily for networking, and need third-party networking libraries (eg, Indy) that can be safely 'stopped'.

Comment: I still don't grasp it, even from the more detailed explanation. You use QueueUserAPC when you want to quit inside a thread and this eventually calls a function that throws an exception and this exception reaches every thread? How are the destructors called and what does the exception throwing function look like? (This whole area of programming is new to me) Thanks!

Comment: @oneminute: The rough idea is that `QueueUserAPC(Thread1, &foo)` causes `Thread1` to call `foo` as soon as it's in an "alertable waitstate". If `foo` throws, the stack of Thread1 is unwound. I.e. you kill one thread at a time, just like `TerminateThread` would do. But unlike `TerminateThread`, RAII mutex locks are unlocked, etc.

Comment: You have a typo:  WaitForSingleObject() needs to be WaitForSIngleObjectEx()

Comment: @John Dibling: Thanks, there were lots of 'em. I use this technique in production code too.

Comment: What if the exception isn't caught?

Comment: @Oneminute The 'outermost' wrapper for each thread function should have a `try...catch (MyThreadExit &e)` in it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a fan of threads checking boolean (or other) status variables to know when to do what, because it's wasteful.  The threads would have to spin, constantly checking the variable to see if there are new instructions.  This burns the CPU.

A better option is to create a semaphore or in Windows an event, and have all the threads wait on that.  The threads can sleep while they arent busy, and wont steal time slices from other threads doing real work simply to check a variable.

Comment: (I'm new to parallel theory) My application is exclusively Windows - How do the threads wait on an event? Any resource you could point me to?

Comment: In Windows, you would use the WaitForSingleObject() family of functions to wait for an event created by CreateEvent().  Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I'm a little confused.. so in each thread I check the return of WaitForSingleObject(exitHandle, 0) to see if the exit event is signaled?

Comment: What is the connection with WaitForSingleObject and exitting the thread? Do you want to set event to be in non-signalled state and then, while thread is waiting, call Terminate thread? Or just let the thread exit when timeout reaches?

Comment: @Kra - more likely the thread would call `WaitForMultipleObjects`, with one handle to allow signalling for exit, and another (or more than one) to allow signalling that work is ready.  If you get a signal on the exit handle, then exit.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as checking a global boolean? You still have to check against the return of waitformultipleobjects to see if the exit handle has been signaled

Comment: @oneminute The advantage of using WaitForMultipleObjects() is that the thread can do nothing efficiently (it just sleeps), but still respond quickly to a request (either to exit, or to do some work). If you check a global boolean, you have to trade off checking frequently (i.e. burning more CPU cycles) or responding slowly to a change in the global boolean (when it changes just after your thread checked it).

Comment: @oneminute - as @Stephen noted, the advantage of this is that threads are only awake when there is really something to do - if there's no work, and no termination, then `WaitForMultipleObjects` does not complete.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now, I'm just thinking in the narrow context of the threads I use which process continuously in which case there isn't a difference. Thanks guys