# QueueUserAPC - throwing exception crashes, possible mingw bug

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, terminate

**Solved:** I upgraded from mingw 4.6.2 to 4.7.0 and it works perfectly, guess it was just a bug

I started to do some research on how terminate a multithreaded application properly and I found those 2 post([first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325286/1393574), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209086/how-do-i-guarantee-fast-shutdown-of-my-win32-app/210385#210385)) about how to use `QueueUserAPC` to signal other threads to terminate.

I thought I should give it a try, and the application keeps crashing when I throw the exception from the APCProc.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

class ExitException
{
public:
    char *desc;
    DWORD exit_code;

    ExitException(char *desc,int exit_code): desc(desc), exit_code(exit_code)
    {}
};

//I use this class to check if objects are deconstructed upon termination
class Test 
{
public:
    char *s;

    Test(char *s): s(s)
    {
        printf("%s ctor\n",s);
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        printf("%s dctor\n",s);
    }
};

DWORD CALLBACK ThreadProc(void *useless)
{
    try
    {
        Test t("thread_test");

        SleepEx(INFINITE,true);

        return 0;
    }
    catch (ExitException &e)
    {
        printf("Thread exits\n%s %lu",e.desc,e.exit_code);
        return e.exit_code;
    }
}

void CALLBACK exit_apc_proc(ULONG_PTR param)
{
    puts("In APCProc");
    ExitException e("Application exit signal!",1);
    throw e;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE thread=CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadProc,NULL,0,NULL);

    Sleep(1000);

    QueueUserAPC(exit_apc_proc,thread,0);

    WaitForSingleObject(thread,INFINITE);

    puts("main: bye");

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why does this happen?

I use mingw for compilation and my OS is 64bit.

Can this be the reason?I read that you shouldn't call `QueueApcProc` from a 32bit app for a thread which runs in a 64bit process or vice versa, but this shouldn't be the case.

**EDIT:** I compiled this with visual studio's c++ compiler 2010 and it worked flawlessly, it is possible that this is a bug in gcc/mingw?

Comment: You are unwinding the stack through a bunch of internal Windows code that calls the APC target.  That could only ever work out if the exception handling implementation is built on top of native Windows SEH exceptions.  It is for MSVC, no problem with this code.  No idea what mingw uses.  It doesn't support catching SEH exceptions so high odds that it doesn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the same thing with VS2005. The problem is that the compiler optimizes the `catch` away. Why? Because according to the C++ standard it's undefined what happens if an `extern "C"` function exits with an exception. So the compiler assumes that `SleepEx` (which is `extern "C"`) does not ever throw. After inlining of `Test::Test` and `Test::~Test` it sees that the `printf` doesn't throw either, and consequently if something in this block exits via an exception

```
    Test t("thread_test");

    SleepEx(INFINITE,true);

    return 0;
```

the behavior is undefined!

In MSVC the code doesn't work with the `/EHsc` switch in Release build, but works with `/EHa` or `/EHs`, which tell it to assume that C function may throw. Perhaps GCC has a similar flag.

Comment: I did a test, and apparently on mingw exceptions work without problems in functions declared with `extern "C"` and im not using any compiler optimization flags

Comment: @lazy_banana: to be sure try moving the SleepEx into a C++ function that will be called indirectly through a volatile pointer.